# RecyclerView - how to update and move item at the same time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sortedlist

I have a RecyclerView Adapter backed by a SortedList. If I make a change to an item, it both changes the item and repositions it in the list.

I've found that if I use `notifyItemChanged` on either the item's starting or ending position, it does not seem to have any effect even in conjunction with `notifyItemMoved`, either before or after.

If I use `notifyItemMoved`, it correctly triggers the movement animation, but the view does not change and still displays the outdated information.

If I use `notifyDatasetChanged` it updates the row and then moves it, but it does so sequentially which is slow, and it obviously notifies the entire list which is not exactly desirable.

Is there any way I can combine the moving and updating animations? And why doesn't `notifyItemChanged` do anything?

Comment: maybe try a `notifiyItemRemove` followed by `notifyItemInsert`

Comment: Short of @SteelBytes `remove`/`insert` idea, @mlyko's `notifyItemChanged(oldPos); notifyItemMoved(oldPos, newPos);` approach seems most likely to work – can anyone confirm whether it does?

Answer (score 6):

In [RecyclerView.Adapter reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemMoved(int,%20int)) is said, that `notifyItemMoved()` is just structural change and therefore won't update data. On the other hand `notifyItemChanged()` is said to be data change.

When calling `notifyItemChanged()`, it will call `RecyclerView#onBindViewHolder()`, so it should update your view.

Working approach for me for updating and moving is:

`notifyItemChanged(oldPos); notifyItemMoved(oldPos, newPos);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SortedList.updateItemAt(int position, Objet newItem)
```

The `newItem` is the updated item, and `position` is the current position. This method replaces the current item for `newItem` and repositions it on the list (and the recyclerview link to it).

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SortedList.html?hl=en#updateItemAt(int,%20T)) is the official documentation.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at DiffUtil
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html

When you update your dataset within your Adapter you can then use this tool to calculate the notifications needed to correctly represent your new data set.

1. Extend `DiffUtil.Callback` and implement the Abstract methods (I create a Constructor that looks like:

   ```
    public MyDiffCallback(ArrayList<String> oldList, ArrayList<String> newList) {

        this.oldList = oldList;
        this.newList = newList;
    }
   ```

I hold the `oldList` and `newList` in memory so that I can implement:

`areItemsTheSame`
`areContentsTheSame`
`getNewListSize`
`getOldListSize`

For example:

```
@Override
public int getOldListSize() {
    return oldList.size();
}
@Override
public int getNewListSize() {
    return newList.size();
}
@Override
public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return oldList.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newList(newItemPosition))
}
@Override
public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
}
```

`areItemsTheSame`: Tells the UTIL if the item has moved (checked position)
`areContentsTheSame`: Informs the UTIL if the contents of the item has changed.

Now in you updateDataSet method (or whatever you have called it!); do something like:

```
public updateDataSet(List newDataSet) {
    // this.dataSet is the old data set / List
    final MyDiffCallback callback = new MyDiffCallback(this.dataSet, newDataSet);
    final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback);

    this.dataSet = newDataSet;
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this); //This is the Adapter
}
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00#.yhxirkkq6